# How to trigger On-Demand scheduled Query in Google Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I created a query in Google Bigquery which is connected to a Topic which triggers the Cloud function. I want to schedule the query on-demand run. Once I schedule the query I am not able to find any option in UI to run that particular Query. Please let me know if some more clarification is required. I only see the following options in scheduled query UI page.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATE Jul/2021**: Google improved its UI, so now it is possible to run scheduled queries on-demand (check [Julio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60428926/how-to-trigger-on-demand-scheduled-query-in-google-bigquery/67077763#67077763) for details).  However, according to him, the command line option described here runs fasters than the UI option.

---

<s>Sadly, you can't.  I don't know if this is a bug or not (probably a bad UI design), but you can't run on-demand scheduled queries via the UI.</s>

This only applies to scheduled queries set to run on-demand.  If your query is scheduled to run in any time frame (daily, weekly, etc), you can make it run on-demand using the option "Schedule backfill".  This option ask you to provide a start date and an end date, so it force all runs that were supposed to run in the given time window (yes, using this option the number of runs will depend of the schedule).  That is, if your query is set to run daily, just provide one day time span that your query will run once.

Alternatively, if you really need to run it on-demand, you will need to use the command line or the API, as shown below.

**Command line solution** (using Cloud Shell):

Run the command:

```
bq mk --transfer_run --run_time "$(date --iso-8601=seconds)" \
  projects/[YOUR_PROJECT]/locations/us/transferConfigs/[YOUR_SCHEDULED_QUERY_GUID]
```

Notice that `YOUR_SCHEDULED_QUERY_ID` is a GUID (it is not the the Scheduled Query name, it looks like `1234a123-1234-1a23-1be9-12ab3c456de7`). You can copy it from the browser URL or get from a list of all scheduled queries running the command `bq ls --transfer_config --transfer_location='us'`.

In all places, change `us` for any other location you may be using (e.g. `eu`).

**API solution**

Use [transferConfigs.startManualRuns API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs/startManualRuns) using the same parameters as the command line option.

Notice the parameter `requestedRunTime` is mandatory.  Its value is only relevant if you use `@run_time` parameter in your query, otherwise it is not used.  You can even hardcode a date if you want.  So just populate it with any valid datetime in the format `2020-08-04T00:00:0Z` and you're done (in the command line solution, I populate it with the command `date --iso-8601=seconds`).

Comment: How can I trigger it using Cloud Function?

Comment: @ThadeuAntonioFerreiraMelo It would be better if describe your needs in details in a new question. However, you probably can develop a Cloud Function that calls the Big Query API (second solution above).

Comment: I need to run Schedule Queries to update some tables on demand, however I don't want to expose users to any code or details about the tables. The only think they need to have access are the tables and datasets. Cloud Functions seems to be just the right solution.

Comment: It does makes sense. Please, create a new question with your inquiry. Your need seems to be useful for me also, so I'll develop a solution for this.

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz The current date part doesn't work for me: --run_time "$(date --iso-8601=seconds)" It returns this error:    
___
```date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnRu] [-r seconds|file] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]]
            [-I[date | hours | minutes | seconds]]
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
Need to specify either both --start_time and --end_time or only --run_time.```

Any thoughts of what I need to simply tell the run_time to equal right now (that is, run the DTS right now)? Thank you!

Comment: @ReidDossinger What's your Shell and Operating System? My bet is that you're using a system with a different implementation for the `date` command.

Answer (score 7):

A bit more late to the party but, you can run it on-demand by clicking on "Schedule backfill", in the pop-up window fill in the boxes with dates from yesterday to today and that's it. This works right for queries which don't depend on current dates (joins, copies, etc).

UPDATE: Now it is even more easier, they implemented a button to run it directly once. Still, I consider it is faster to use [Diego Queiroz 's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63257918/3533555), as it runs the process 2x faster than this way.

[image: scheduled_queries]

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your Bigquery job runs correctly before scheduling and that your problem is focused on the fact that you cannot run manually the query after Scheduling. Please confirm if I misunderstood.

You can find the code of you query if you click on your Scheduled Query and then select Configuration (on the top of the page).  Under "Data source details" you can see "Query string".

Indeed, you cannot run directly this query from here but you can alternatively use a [BigQuery View](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views) using the "Query string" obtained above. BigQuery Views enable to "Update" a query whenever you run them. Let me know if you need further clarification regarding this.

Comment: Yes Fernando my Query runs correctly so no issue in Query. I only thing is I have to trigger a Topic(pub/sub) when the query execution is completed. Which is only possible when we create a schedule query, if we are running directly from Query editor it doesn't trigger the Topic.  When I was scheduling the Query it had an option to schedule it on-demand, but I can't find any option to trigger the Query once i have created it. I am not aware of Bigquery View, please let me know if it solves my problem.

Comment: No, you cannot edit anything after creating a scheduled query. However, you can create a new scheduled query enabling Cloud Pub/Sub topic. 
As I said, you can take the code of the query from your scheduled query, so recreating it with this new option should not take a lot of time.

Comment: Actually my query is very big and deals with GB's of data. So when I have to recreate a schedule query then the bigquery UI takes a lot of time to compile it and sometimes the browser is crashed.

Comment: You don't have to Run the query before creating a new schedule query. Also, what do you mean by "the browser is crashed". The job is performed as VM. Are you exceeding any of the limits [stated here?](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui#web_ui_display_limits)

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party but this is available now as "RUN TRANSFER NOW" for On-Demand queries.

[image]

Comment: why can't google just put a button called "RUN NOW". I don't understand why they always make things more confusing than they are.