# Bigquery - Version Control Scheduled Queries

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bq

Right now I have scheduled queries via BQ interface. They work but do not scale or migrate very well (across dev and prod gcp projects). So I am trying to do scheduled queries in a way that is reproducible, scalable and migrate-able.

My queries are complicated and hence I am struggling with `'`, `"` and `'''` to make it run via `bq` commands and schedule via github actions.

[This is the query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70685951/2296728) which is most complicated:

```
declare bq_last_id int64;
declare external_sql string;
set bq_last_id = (select max(id) from bq_dataset.bq_table);
set external_sql = '"select * from mysql_table where id > ('|| bq_last_id ||')"';
execute immediate 'select * from external_query("my-gcp-project.my-region.my-connection-name",'|| external_sql || ');'
```

In total there are 20 something queries that have to scheduled. This one is the only one which is incremental or other are drop and recreate table again so they are not as complicated as this one.

WHAT I HAVE TRIED TILL NOW:

- creating an on-demand query in BQ interface and then using `bq mk` command to run it with timestamp as a variable as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63257918/2296728) answer. The problem with it is I still have to manually create the on-demand queries and I will have to do separately in dev and prod projects.
- I am unable to find a way to create on-demand query using `bq` cmd.
- I am unable to `bq query` to run the queries (that is not create bq scheduled queries at all). and then later schedule them via gihub action.

Any help with correct syntax or better suggestions to do this will be super helpful to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using a tool for your materialization and transformation?  Look at DBT (getdbt.com) for example.

Comment: Yes already using dbt. The query I shared above is not something easily implementable.
I asked dbt slack community and got no response. I read on SO and it looks like `execute immediate` is not really working in dbt models or sources.

Answer (score 1):

The way I use to solve problems with scape characters when inserting queries in `bq` commands is using `jq` on shell and my queries on a file, as following:

1. create `queries.sql` file with your query script:

```
cat queries.sql
```

```
declare bq_last_id int64;
declare external_sql string;
set bq_last_id = (select max(id) from bq_dataset.bq_table);
set external_sql = '"select * from mysql_table where id > ('|| bq_last_id ||')"';
execute immediate 'select * from external_query("my-gcp-project.my-region.my-connection-name",'|| external_sql || ');'
```

2. Create the following script:
   schedule_query.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -f #avoind * used as wildcard
json=$(jq -nc --arg query "$(<queries.sql)" '{ "query": $query }')

#adapt the command and param to work in your environment (destination, tables, etc...)
bq mk \
--transfer_config \
--target_dataset=mydataset \
--display_name='My Scheduled Query' \
--params="$json" \
--data_source=scheduled_query \
--service_account_name=abcdef-test-sa@abcdef-test.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```