# Using Airflow BashOperator to trigger a Scheduled BQ gives me a fatal flag positioning error

Tags: bash, google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to trigger an on demand BigQuery query through a bash command in a Cloud Composer instance (Airflow). I'm using a BashOperator in order to run a `bq` command like this:

```
bq mk --transfer_run \
--run_time="<iso timestamp>" \
--service_account_name=<service account> \
--project_id=<project> \
projects/<project>/locations/us/transferConfigs/<query id>
```

On my terminal this fine, but when I use Airflow like so:

```
bq_command = BashOperator(
         task_id = "bq_command",
         bash_command = f"""
         bq mk --transfer_run \
         --run_time={{ ts }} \
         --service_account_name=svc-@company_name-{{ var.value.environment }}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
         --project_id=<project_name> \
         projects/{project_id}/locations/us/transferConfigs/630b2bb7-0000-2759-9382-14223bb2349e
         """
     )
```

I get error messages like this:

```
FATAL Flags positioning error: Flag '--project_id=<project_name>' appears after final command line argument. Please reposition the flag.
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

PD:

- the reason why we want to go down this route is because we have monitoring and a support team looking over airflow and not BQ.
- i looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60428926/how-to-trigger-on-demand-scheduled-query-in-google-bigquery) to setup the bash command before making this post

Comment: I agree with indenting arguments like this, but it looks like Airflow is getting confused. I would fold everything onto one line and see if that works. THEN you can spend time  (if you can spare it) to fix the escaping of the line endings (`"\"`), maybe with 2 - 5 `"\"` at the end. I use dbl-quotes to work around formatting "features" of posting code in comments (-;!  Good luck.

Comment: i just tried that but it's still failing unfortunately.

Comment: Why not use [BigQueryDataTransferServiceStartTransferRunsOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/bigquery_dts.html#manually-starting-transfer-runs) instead using bq command line?